# Cannot write comments in Facebook - nothing happens

Tags: facebook

I have been unable to write comments on Facebook for several month in Chrome.

After typing, neither Enter nor Ctrl+Enter nor clicking on Post do anything - the page simply stays static without any indication of my action.

This happens on all pages, of foreign people as well as friends (in good standing, not blocked), and even on my own posts on my owl wall. I am not aware of ever acting contrary to the TOS. Other functionality is not affected to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing up the question made me think of a potential problem - I'm leaving this here for future reference.

I had the "Social Fixer for Facebook" extension installed. Disabling it made the problem disappear and I can again write comments as expected.

Comment: Ah, "rubber duck debugging". A useful tool.